# React native webview injectedJavascript auto fill webform

Tags: javascript, reactjs, forms, react-native, webview

So here is what I wish to make it work, I am using a webview to load zara site, their login form email element you can inspect here https://www.zara.com/uk/en/logon  `<input id="email" name="email" type="text" value="" autocomplete="off"`

and I wish when my app webview lands on zara login page, react native app can auto fill the login email and password field.
Below is my attampt:
import React from 'react';

```
import { StyleSheet } from 'react-native';
import { WebView } from 'react-native-webview';

export default function ZaraWebView() {
  return (
    <WebView
      source={{uri: 'https://www.zara.com/uk'}}  
      injectedJavaScript={`(function(){document.getElementById('email').value = 'test@test.com';} 
());`}    
      style={{flex: 1, marginTop: 30}}
    />
  );
}
```

But it does not seem working, any example suggestions?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I had something similar, and when i removed the style from the Webview component it worked. I wrapped the Webview component in a View component, and applied the same style to that and it worked as expected.